# Is it possible to access vertex values of an object created using display lists?

Tags: opengl, collision-detection

I wanted to learn to develop games so started with tetris. I encountered a problem right in the beginning. My game is 20% ready. There are five types of shapes viz YELL, BOX, LINE, TEE, YEL which are shapes of different kinds. I created five display lists like this

```
#define YELL 1
#define BOX 2
#define LINE 3
#define TEE 4
#define YEL 5
int bs=20;
void defineshapes()
{
glNewList(YELL,GL_COMPILE);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(-bs,0,0);
    glColor3fv(color[color1]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(0,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,-bs);
    glVertex2i(0,-bs);
    glEnd();
    glTranslated(bs,0,0);
    glColor3fv(color[color2]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(0,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,-bs);
    glVertex2i(0,-bs);
    glEnd();
    glTranslated(bs,0,0);
    glColor3fv(color[color3]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(0,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,-bs);
    glVertex2i(0,-bs);
    glEnd();
    glTranslated(-2*bs,-bs,0);
    glColor3fv(color[color4]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(0,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,0);
    glVertex2i(bs,-bs);
    glVertex2i(0,-bs);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
glEndList();
glNewList(BOX,GL_COMPILE);
    glPushMatrix();
      .....
```

and randomly picking one like this

```
srand(time(NULL));
color1=rand()%6;
color2=rand()%6;
color3=rand()%6;
color4=rand()%6;
defineshapes();
randshape=rand()%5+1;
```

and drawing in display function like this

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(x2,y2,0);
    glCallList(randshape);
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}
```

I expected problem in the beginning itself when i used the display lists because i had to access the vertex values(x,y) of the shapes to check if they might overlap with another block below before moving them down. Is there a way of knowing the vertex values of objects drawn using display lists.

I encountered the same problem once before when i needed to create a tyre of a car. I wanted the tyre to be painted with colors so created a mesh by rotating a circle again using display lists. Then i needed to know the values of the intersection points of longitudes and latitudes which i didnt know how to get so i abandoned that task.

A YELL looks like this
[image: YELL]

What is the easiest method of getting around this problem. I am sure OpenGL has a way of getting this done but i am new to it.

Comment: Forget immediate rendering mode! It's deprecated since OpenGL 3.0 and OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but i don't even know which version of OpenGL i have learnt. Code samples in this site often use glew.h but i have used only glut.h till now. Things like VBO are greek and latin to me. I feel like i am living in the dinosaur era. Very embarrassing.

Comment: Well, that's OpenGL for you -- it's difficult to find documentation, the API is crufty and it's not easy to tell modern vs deprecated code apart at a glance.  I would recommend http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ as one of the few places to actually learn about modern OpenGL.

Comment: @sean thanks for the link. Thanks everyone for the comments and answers. I just wanted to try out something different. May be learning maya or 3dsmax might help me in modelling some interesting/complex objects.

Comment: http://cglabprojects.blogspot.in/2013/07/tetris-game.html ..... I finished the game but did not detect the finish still :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to look at the vertex data inside a display list.  Even using more modern technology like VBOs or whatever, while you can look at the vertex data after you set it up, it's not necessarily a good idea to do so (it could cause performance problems if you try to look at the data while the GPU is using it).

In any case, it's not necessary.  Just keep your own copy of the data in your own structures and you can look at it whenever you want.  In fact, for collision detection for Tetris you don't even really want vertex data; it's much simpler if you just keep track of which grid squares are occupied or not.

Comment: If its not taxing you too much how will you know which blocks are occupied after rotating a TEE or YELL esp if you are not going to store vertex data(Assuming binary info stored for occupied/unoccupied). What kind of mathematics may be involved here? Can i post this as a question in the math site.

Comment: @MukeshKamath You'd just have a small 2D array for each block shape that defines which grid squares it occupies, and when you rotate the block you rotate the array.  Since the rotations are by 90 degrees it's easy to do this by just looping over the array elements in a different order.